# Lifetime of object executing an asynchronous task

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

I have the code below:

```
void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var service = new MyService();
    service.LoginCompleted += (sender2, e2) =>
    {
        //closes the animated loading dialog and show the logged in screen
    };

    service.LoginAsync("user", "password");
    //starts an animated "loading" dialog
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this as I don't know if GC could remove the `MyService` instance from memory while the `LoginAsync` method is waiting for completion and the `LoginCompleted` event never being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there are any references to the MyService object the GC won't delete the object. So if LoginAsync has any references to the MyService object which I assume it has, it won't be GC'ed.